# Hackerrank "Sherlock Holmes" challenge

Tags: java, array, programming-challenge

> Watson gives to Sherlock an array: `A1, A2, ⋯, AN`. He also gives to
>   Sherlock two other arrays: `B1, B2, ⋯, BM` and `C1, C2, ⋯, CM`. Then Watson asks
>   Sherlock to perform the following program:
>
> ```
>   for i = 1 to M do
>    for j = 1 to N do
>      if j % B[i] == 0 then
>          A[j] = A[j] * C[i]
>     endif
>  end do
> end do
> ```
>
> Can you help Sherlock and tell him the resulting array A? You should print all the array elements modulo (1000000007).
>
> #### Input Format
>
> The first line contains two integer numbers N and M. The
>   next line contains N integers, the elements of array A. The next two
>   lines contains M integers each, the elements of array B and C.
>
> #### Output Format
>
> Print N integers, the elements of array A after
>   performing the program modulo (1000000007).
>
> #### Sample Input
>
> ```
> 4 3
> 1 2 3 4
> 1 2 3
> 13 29 71
> ```
>
> #### Sample Output
>
> ```
> 13 754 2769 1508
> ```

If we brute force, it will time out.  Please suggest ways on making this efficient.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class SherlockArray {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String line1 = in.nextLine();
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line1, " ");

    int n = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
    int m = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
    Long[] b = new Long[m];

    String strA = in.nextLine();
    String[] stA = strA.split(" ");
    BigInteger aBI[] = new BigInteger[n];
    for (int ia = 0; ia < stA.length; ia++) {
        aBI[ia] = new BigInteger(stA[ia]);
    }

    String strB = in.nextLine();
    String[] stB = strB.split(" ");
    for (int ib = 0; ib < stB.length; ib++) {
        b[ib] = Long.parseLong(stB[ib]);
    }

    String strC = in.nextLine();
    String[] st3 = strC.split(" ");
    for (int ic = 0; ic < m; ic++) {
        for (int index = b[ic].intValue(); index <= n; index += b[ic]
                .intValue()) {
            aBI[index - 1] = aBI[index - 1].multiply(new BigInteger(st3[ic]));
        }
    }

    for (int ia = 0; ia < n; ia++) {
        aBI[ia] = aBI[ia].mod(new BigInteger("1000000007"));
        System.out.print(aBI[ia] + " ");
    }

}


}
```

Comment: This is https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/sherlock-and-queries (as OP stated in a comment to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25503080/improvising-the-code-block).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A far more optimal solution involves keeping track of the number of times that `B[i]` occurs.

This is because for every multiple of `B[i]`: `B[i]`, `2 * B[i]`, ..., `j * B[i]`, we multiply `A[i * j]` by `C[i]`

This yields the following info for the example:

1 occurs 4 times (4 multiples), 2 occurs 2 times (2 multiples), 3 occurs 1 time (3 multiples), 4 occurs 1 time (1 multiple)

Therefore, we multiply 1 by 13, 2 by 13, 3 by 13, 4 by 13 (first 4 multiples of 1)

we multiply 2 by 29, 4 by 29 (first 2 multiples of 2)

we multiply 3 by 71 (first multiple of 3)

we multiply 4 by 1 (since `C[4]` doesn't exist)

This yields a net result of multiplying 1 by 13, 2 by 13 * 29, 3 by 13 * 71, 4 by 13 * 29

This approach ends up being \$O(N * log(N))\$ because for each N, you do N/i multiplications, meaning you do a total of:

```
N/1 + N/2 + N/3 + N/4 + ... N/N = N * (1/1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + ... + 1/N) = O(Nlog(N)),
```

since (1/1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + ...) is the [harmonic series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)) and grows with \$O(log(N))\$

Here is the relevant code, which produced the results in under 2 seconds, mostly due to very inefficient I/O. I changed BigIntegers to Longs, as BigIntegers are very **SLOW** in Java. I also repeatedly used modulo multiplication. These two suggestions were brought up by rofl, but I wanted to re-iterate them.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
       Long N = scanner.nextLong();
       Long M = scanner.nextLong();
       scanner.nextLine();

       ArrayList<Long> A = new ArrayList<Long>();
       ArrayList<Long> B = new ArrayList<Long>();
       ArrayList<Long> C = new ArrayList<Long>();

       A.add(0L);
       for (String string : scanner.nextLine().split(" ")) {
           A.add(new Long(string));
       }
       B.add(0L);
       for (String string : scanner.nextLine().split(" ")) {
           B.add(new Long(string));
       }
       C.add(0L);
       for (String string : scanner.nextLine().split(" ")) {
           C.add(new Long(string));
       }

       HashMap<Long, Long> counts = new HashMap<Long, Long>();

       for (int i = 1; i < M+1; i++) {
           if (counts.containsKey(B.get(i))) {
               counts.put(B.get(i), (counts.get(B.get(i)) * C.get(i)) % 1000000007L);
           }
           else {
               counts.put(B.get(i), C.get(i));
           }
       }

       for (Long i = 1L; i < N+1; i++) {
           for (Long j = 1L; j < (N / i) + 1L; j++) {
               if (counts.containsKey(i)) {
                   A.set((int)(i * j), (A.get((int)(i * j)) * counts.get(i)) % 1000000007L); 
               }
           }
       }

       System.out.print(A.get(1));
       for (int i = 2; i < A.size(); i++) {
           System.out.print(" " + A.get(i));
       }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @mleyfman for the effort on code as well.. It made things clear for me.. 
This was my first post and got a wonderful support! Thanks again all! :)

Answer (score 15):

In 1801, a guy called Carl Friedrich Gauss studied problems where the number line wrapped around, [called Modular Arithmetic.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Congruence_relation)

In his studies, he proved that:

$$
    (a \times b)\ \%\ n = [(a)\ \%\ n \times (b)\ \%\ n]\ \%\ n
$$

Also, 1000000007 is a prime number which means that there are other benefits...

And, it is also just less than half of `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Finally, two int values, no matter how large, when multiplied, will never be larger than `Long.MAX_VALUE`

Putting this all together, you can rewrite your code without the `BigInteger` math, something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
        if (j % B[i] == 0) {
            A[j] = (int)( ( (long) A[j] * C[i]) % 1000000007L);
        }
    }
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(A));
```

So, using some math, you can avoid the BigInteger problem entirely, and keep things as `long` and `int` values.

I imagine that this will be enough of a performance improvement to avoid the timeout.

Note, that for large numbers, BigInteger has \$O(s)\$ type complexity where s is the magnitude of the number, when doing multiplication. The bigger the number, the slower the product. Thus, your complexity for your current solution is \$O(nms)\$ where n is the size of the A array, m is the size of the B and C arrays, and s is the average size of the BigIntegers used. By reducing the problem to int-size values, we reduce the time complexity by a full order to just\$O(nm)\$.

There are likely ways for you to be able to solve the math in O(n) time as well.... I just need to think about how to restructure the `if` condition in the loops

Answer (score 7):

The original post used 1-based arrays.  If you change them to 0-based, you should test (j+1)%B[i] == 0, not j%B[i] == 0.

```
for (int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
    if ((j+1) % B[i] == 0) {
        ...
    }
}
```

And that can be rewritten:

```
for (int j = B[i]-1; j < M; j+=B[i]) {
    ...
}
```

It can be faster depending how large the B[i] are.

Comment: You should still start with `int j = 0`. And it is faster even with `B[i]==1` (avoids a division)

Comment: Oops, indeed!.  Fixed.  Er...  But the original code starts the loops with 1.  So it is wrong either way.

Comment: Fixed again to adjust for 0-based arrays.

Answer (score 2):

Other answers already deal with

- using modular (`long`) integer arithmetic (rolfl)
- speeding up the inner loop by predicting the outcome of the `if` (Florian F)

A third possible speedup consists of grouping equal \$B\$ values together. If the same value \$B_i\$ occurs \$k\$ times, you can handle them all together with \$k - 1 + \frac{M}{B}\$ modular multiplications instead of \$\frac{kM}{B}\$.

Using these three optimizations my worst test case took 0.19s, and I didn't even make use of another general optimization (for HackerRank and similar competitions) — namely to make sure that my I/O is fast even for large input.

Comment: Hagen, was that `k - 1 + M/B` or `(k - 1 + M)/B`? Your use of parentheses kind of confused me...